# Use AntiForgeryToken with ASP.NET core and Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

i had a problem with asp.net core [image]with antiforgerytoken filter.

[image]

Comment: do not post code as images & at least translate what does the error says on the second picture.